# Optimizing JTextArea Text Drawing

Tags: java, jtextarea

So, I'm trying to make a little program to display chat logs from a certain app in a custom way. I alredy built my GUI, and I can read the messages from the .txt file. My problem is, when I print them on the console, the program takes about 1.5 seconds to process the 17k line file. But, when I try to show the text on the GUI, it takes around a minute and a half, and I have no idea why.

To read the text from the file, I'm using a BufferedReader. And to show the text on a JTextArea, and all I'm doing is the following:

```
JTextArea.append(myString+"\n");
```

My test file is around 1,000,000 characters long, if that's any help. I'd really like to know what's happening, and maybe some advice on how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Pagination , You doesn't need to read the whole file and show it  in `JTextArea`, try to  read a part of the file and show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder to build the String and then just call setText() once one the TextArea so you don't force a repaint of the area for each line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame =new JFrame();
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            area.append(i+"\n");
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("(t2-t1) = " + (t2-t1));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            sb.append(i+"\n");
        }
        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        area.setText(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("(t4-t3) = " + (t4-t3));

    });
}
```

prints:

```
(t2-t1) = 2871
(t4-t3) = 26
```

The first time difference was measured with JTextArea.append() the second with StringBuilder.append() followed by JTextArea.setText().

Comment: Well, that certainly helped, altho it still takes a long time for the text to show up in the JTextArea. Still, thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's the only one, but just so people know if they ever encounter the same problem:

I ended up changing the JTextArea for a JTable. Then I read each individual message on my file to an ArrayList, and finally I copy that to an Object[] array so I can update the TableModel. No noticeable delay with a 22k line file.